# How to develop for multiple platforms

Tags: ios, apache-flex, multiplatform

I have made my first app in the Android platform. However this is not the only platform and I want to get my apps published on at least Android and iOS platforms.
I would like to have one developing platform for both platforms. What is the options?
I have now tried Flex, Air with Flash Builder. It seems quite promising but the future seems to be a bit uncertain and are also more expansive.
It would be interesting to have some suggestions about what developing tools to focus on if I would like to develop apps on both Android and iOS.

Comment: A bad thing I discovered today about Adobe AIR is that it doesn't support many phones - such as my own HTC Wildfire S. So beware, if you plan on making your application work on as many phones as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of apps you want to build (i.e. Games, Content Aggregators, etc.) because each 3rd party "App-Generator" that deploys to multiple platforms has their strengths and weaknesses.

**Here's a (brief) list:**

[Appcelerator's Titanium SDK](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/) - leverages mobile-browser-based features, mostly for content-aggregators, simple or core feature list on platforms

[Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) - leverages LUA-scripting language for 2d / more simple games and applications; has a growing user-base and community; possible to leverage for core-experience as well

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/#mobile) - 3d experience, games, usually for more high-end, premium experiences

If you're going to develop on the platform, I always recommend **build to that platform's language** since you'll never have to worry about what happens when the language is upgraded and your "app-generator" hasn't upgraded yet.

It will also help you to learn the language on that platform (Java, C#, Objective-C, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very mutch!
I am going to have a look at Titanium and Corona. Have just started with Corona.

Comment: If you appreciate the answer I gave, let me know by accepting it as an answer (or telling me how I can better improve it?) :D

Comment: I have now get a quick look at Appcelerator and Corona. I think both of these and Flashbuilder can produce what I need. Which of them do you think is the best choice in the long run.

Comment: What kind of app do you want to produce? The suggestions I have above depend both on the kind of app as well as your language preferences. Flashbuilder uses AS3, Corona is LUA, and Appcelerator is HTML / CSS / Javascript. I recommend starting with the language you're best familiar with to get ramped up quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old topic but for those who are still looking for rapid mobile development there is also [Kinetise](https://www.kinetise.com/) that is code-less tool and offers also backend system/CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sybase Unwired Platform. It has Device App Designer which can create applications for Blackberry ,Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for high quality, I don't think there is any other way than going native for each platform. Also keep in mind that different platforms have different UI guidelines and principles, and doing a multiplatform project is not a good enough reason to abandon those guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend phonegap: http://www.phonegap.com